# Redux useSelector filtering on object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-hooks

So I'm using redux and useSelector hook to get data from store.

I can filter specific data in a reducer array, so that the component only updates when the filtered data is changed, for example:

```
const images = useSelector(state => state.Reducer.images.filter(x => x.id === someID));
```

However, when I try the same sort of thing with an object, the component always re-renders even if the store hasn't even changed. e.g.:

```
const images = useSelector(state => Object.keys(state.Reducer.images)
  .filter(x => x === someID)
  .reduce((arr, key) => {
    arr.push(state.Reducer.images[key].data);
    return arr;
  }, []));
```

Why is this happening and how do I get it only to update when the data has changed? Am assuming passing some deep comparison function into useSelector?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be able to avoid these re-renders by using `shallowEqual`.  This will prevent the new references from being considered different all the time.

```
const images = useSelector(state => Object.keys(state.Reducer.images)
  .filter(x => x === someID)
  .reduce((arr, key) => {
    arr.push(state.Reducer.images[key].data);
    return arr;
  }, []), shallowEqual);
```

https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#equality-comparisons-and-updates